# Advanced Filter - Remove rows based on multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a spreadsheet where I want to filter out Rows on multiple criteria.

The first filter would be to find all rows with no Scale ID (column M), and to remove this row and any row with the same Prd #, Production company, Prj #, and project title (Column F, G, H, I).

So using the picture for example, I would want to remove Row 12 and Row 13 because the Scale ID in Row 13 is blank, and the Prd #, Production company, Prj #, and project title are the same for both Row 12 and Row 13.

Secondly, I want to remove all the rows where the Prd #, Production company, Prj #, and project title (Column F, G, H, and I) are the same, BUT the System Loc, Season Code, PrCO and Bank Code are different (Column O, P, Q, and R).

So for example Row 54 - Row 57 have the same Prd #, Production company, Prj #, and project title, BUT the System Loc, Season Code, PrCO and Bank Code are different, so I would want to remove all four of these rows.

[image: Data]

Comment: 1) Which version of Excel is the solution needed for (the question tags indicate this will need to work for Excel 2007)?  2) Are you filtering, hiding or deleting the rows?  3) Even if you are filtering, would you consider VBA?

Comment: The solution is needed for excel 2016. I would like to filter these rows out preferably, as my goal is to print a list of the data I want to see. I would prefer a formula solution, rather than VBA.

Comment: Create a helper column with an array formula which provides a filterable indicator according to the criteria you set forth.

Comment: @fixer1234, you may have meant to refer to my suboptimal edit, I'll use the format you showed going forward, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a filter column and paste this formula into row 2 of the column (even if the data rows are further down)

`=COUNTIFS($M$2:$M$16,"",$F$2:$F$16,$F2,$G$2:$G$16,$G2,$H$2:$H$16,$H2,$I$2:$I$16,$I2)+COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$16,$F2,$G$2:$G$16,$G2,$H$2:$H$16,$H2,$I$2:$I$16,$I2,$O$2:$O$16,"<>"&$O2)+COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$16,$F2,$G$2:$G$16,$G2,$H$2:$H$16,$H2,$I$2:$I$16,$I2,$P$2:$P$16,"<>"&$P2)+COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$16,$F2,$G$2:$G$16,$G2,$H$2:$H$16,$H2,$I$2:$I$16,$I2,$Q$2:$Q$16,"<>"&$Q2) +COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$16,$F2,$G$2:$G$16,$G2,$H$2:$H$16,$H2,$I$2:$I$16,$I2,$R$2:$R$16,"<>"&$R2)`

2. Now copy drag the formula down to the row where the data starts.
3. Delete the formula from the cells above.
4. Click on the formula cell then click in the formula bar.
   All the formulas' addressed cells should be highlighted on the sheet.
5. Carefully adjust each highlighted column range so that it:

   - Extends to the end of the data.
   - Begins at the row the data starts in.
   - Is the same size as all the other column ranges.
   - Leave the single cell range alone at the beginning of each column of data.
     This single cell range should overlap with the first cell of the column range.

Here is a formatted look at the helper column formula.

```
=COUNTIFS( $M$2:$M$16, "", $F$2:$F$16, $F2, $G$2:$G$16, $G2, $H$2:$H$16, $H2, $I$2:$I$16, $I2)
+ COUNTIFS( $F$2:$F$16, $F2, $G$2:$G$16, $G2, $H$2:$H$16, $H2, $I$2:$I$16, $I2, $O$2:$O$16, "<>"&$O2)
+ COUNTIFS( $F$2:$F$16, $F2, $G$2:$G$16, $G2, $H$2:$H$16, $H2, $I$2:$I$16, $I2, $P$2:$P$16, "<>"&$P2)
+ COUNTIFS( $F$2:$F$16, $F2, $G$2:$G$16, $G2, $H$2:$H$16, $H2, $I$2:$I$16, $I2, $Q$2:$Q$16, "<>"&$Q2)
+ COUNTIFS( $F$2:$F$16, $F2, $G$2:$G$16, $G2, $H$2:$H$16, $H2, $I$2:$I$16, $I2, $R$2:$R$16, "<>"&$R2)
```

To use the formated formula, with the appropriate cell selected, paste this formula directly to the formula bar. (Otherwise the formula will split across multiple rows.)

**How it works:**

- The first line determines if there are any blanks in row M which have the same Column F, G, H & I values as the current formula's row F, G, H & I values respectively.
- The result is added to the following results to get a cumulative OR value.
- The next 4 lines create a cumulative logical OR for any rows which have the same Column F, G, H, and I values as the formula row, but a different Column O value OR a different Column P value OR a different Column Q value OR a different Column R value than the current formulas row Column O, P, Q, and R values respectively.
- Any value greater than zero met the criteria and should be filtered out.
  **Filter on the helper Column, only showing rows with a zero value.**
  Or wrap in equals zero `=( CountIfs()...+CountIfs() )=0`, Filter `True`.